# None of the valid provisioning profiles include the devices - Distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I read online we need a separate distribution provisioning profile if we want to distribute an app to the app store. I know there are answers already on StackOverflow for this error but I think mine pertains to my Distribution provisioning profile.

So right now I have two provision profiles, one for developer, and another for distribution. The app will build and run successfully on the same device when Code Signing Identity under "Build Settings" is set to iOS Developer. But when I switch Code Signing Identity to iOS Distribution and run on the same device, I get the error "None of the valid provisioning profiles include the devices". When I try the option to let Xcode "fix the issue", it says that

```
"Xcode failed to resolve the issue. Check your code signing settings; ensure you have a matching signing certificate and provisioning profile installed; and try again."
```

The provisioning profile for distribution is active on the Apple Developer site. When I try to reset in Preferences I still get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not run on a device with the Distribution profile. That's just for doing a build/archive and then submitting that to the store. If you want to run the production build on your device, submit to iTunes Connect and use TestFlight to install that build on your device.

Comment: Or do an Ad Hoc build.